# Pagination showing blank content area

Tags: pagination

ExpressionEngine greenhorn here...

I'm trying to output some pagination and run into blank pages when I click any of the links (page 1, 2, 3, Next/Last etc...). The numbered list of pages also jumps up by multiples 6... which sets of alarm bells because my channel below has a limit of 6.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="6" dynamic="off" orderby="date" sort="desc" paginate="bottom"}
                 {paginate}

                       <p id="pagination">Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
                    {/paginate} 
<!-- SOME ENTRIES -->
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: the pagination links link to /P6, P/12, P/18, and so on in multiples of 6. I have a limit set to six in Channel Entries. Is this something other folks have come across?

Comment: The numbers after the /P represent the offset, not the page number, so they are correct being in multiple of your limit. That is, page 2, means you're looking at an offset of 6, entries 7 through 12.

Answer (score 2):

Try following instructions on [Blank Pages](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/troubleshooting/general/blank_pages.html) in EE docs and see if you get any errors reported.

Answer (score 1):

The sample code you have provided looks right and is an exact copy of what is provided in the user guide under pagination. I also tested it in my site and it works correctly.

The issue then must be caused by other code inside the channel entries tag.

Comment out chunks of the code and test it yourself until it works/doesnt work.

Maybe youve used a plugin tag that is causing the conflict.

Edit: After checking your code in your earlier question spotted a tag for slideshow and suggest if you remove that code things will work.

And a search for slideshow leads me to suggest its custom code thats been written and is causing the conflict.

If you place this inside the slideshow tag, (i think) youll get a result that is causing the conflict with pagination

```
{total_pages}
```

Am i correct?